# Code runs when refresh

Tags: php, button, refresh

Why is this code running when I refresh page? Is somethink wrong with condition isset($_POST['topuj'])? "Topuj" is name of button.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['prihlaseny'])) {
require('db.php');
$meno1 = $_COOKIE['prihlaseny'];

$prikaz = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `uzivatelia` WHERE `meno`='{$meno1}'");
while($a = $prikaz->fetch_assoc()) {
$kredit = $a[kredity_topovania];
$plus = $a[topovanie];

if( $kredit > 0) {
echo "
<form method='post'>";
if( $kredit == 1) echo "Máš $kredit kredit."; 
if( $kredit == 2 || $kredit == 3 || $kredit == 4) echo "Máš $kredit kredity."; 
if( $kredit > 4) echo "Máš $kredit kreditov."; 
echo "<br /><button name='topuj' value='$a[id]' />Topovať</button>
</form>
";}

}
if( isset($_POST['topuj'])) {
$id = $_POST['topuj'];
$mysql->query("UPDATE `uzivatelia` SET topovanie='$plus'+1, kredity_topovania='$kredit'-1 WHERE id='{$id}'");
}
```

Comment: Is a part of it running or is everything running?

Comment: If you press f5, does your browser ask you to resend form data?

Comment: You would be sending the post data again ( most browser does it)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely experiencing the *"double submit problem"*

If the last HTTP request made by a browser was a POST request with data payload (in your case inputs from a form) and you refresh/reload the webpage the browser will re-submit the POST data.
Which will obviously trigger your `isset($_POST['topuj'])` condition.

The browser will generally issue a warning that it is going to do this.

If you are developing and you want to avoid this, I would browse back to the form by re-typing the URL in the address bar or clicking a link back to the form.

For a production app you may want to implement a better solution to prevent the user being able to reload the page.
For example redirect the user away from the page after a successful submission, but there are many (possibly better) solutions as well.